# Geopandas: How to associate a Point to a Linestring using the original Linestring order

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

Using Geopandas, Shapely

Suppose I have a Linestring that represents a (cornered) street:

LineString([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)]

Note that the order of points in this linestring matters because LineString([(1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 2)] would represent a very different street.

Now, suppose I have list of points that **belong** to my street:

Point((1.9, 1.9))

Point((1.5, 1.5))

Point((2.5, 1.5))

Point((1.2, 1.2))

I want to create a new Linestring where all the Points are "merged" with the original street coordinates. This "merge" mechanism has to maintain the original street shape as follows:

LineString([**(1, 1)**, (1.2, 1.2), (1.5, 1.5), (1.9, 1.9), **(2, 2)**, (2.5, 1.5). **(3, 1)**]

Any ideas how to approach this?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
street = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'street': ['st'], 'geometry': LineString([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)])})
pp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [Point((1.9, 1.9)), Point((1.5, 1.5)), Point((2.5, 1.5)), Point((1.2, 1.2))]})
print(street)
print(pp)
```

Comment: Take a look at the shapely's  `LineString.project()` method. You can use it to sort all your points (external points and street points) in terms of the street's total length. You can also use it in tandem with the `LineString.interpolate()` method to figure out if the point really does belong to the street or not.

Comment: Thanks Felipe. Not quite what i need. As i said, my points BELONG to linestring. So interpolating Point(1.2, 1.2) with the original linestring will return Point(1.2, 1.2). What im looking for is to create a NEW linestring that would contain newly introduced points in such way that the original shape would not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a lengthy-ish approach if you already know which points belong to which streets:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

street = shapely.geometry.LineString([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)])
pp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [shapely.geometry.Point(pt) for pt in [(1.9, 1.9), 
                                                                          (1.5, 1.5), 
                                                                          (2.5, 1.5), 
                                                                          (1.2, 1.2)]],
                       'origin':'external'},
                      geometry='geometry')

ps = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'origin':'street',
                       'geometry':[shapely.geometry.Point(pt) for pt in list(street.coords)]},
                      geometry='geometry')

p_all = pd.concat([pp, ps], ignore_index=True)

p_all['dist_along_line'] = p_all['geometry'].apply(lambda p: street.project(p))

p_all = p_all.sort_values(by='dist_along_line')

final_geom = shapely.geometry.LineString(p_all['geometry'].values)

print(p_all)

print(final_geom.wkt)
```

Note how, in my code, the `street` variable isn't a GeoDataFrame but a simple shapely `Linestring` instead.

The `final_geom` variable will contain the sorted points as you wanted, while the `p_all` variable will contain a GeoDataFrame with the sorted list of all the points. I've also added a "origin" column so you can tell which points came from the original `street` geometry and which ones came from the `pp` GeoDataFrame of external points.

[image: plotted line and resulting geodataframe]

## Caveat

Note that this approach will only work with `LineString`s. If some streets are coded as `MultiLineString`s, you'll have to take care of them differently in the `ps = ....` statement.

Comment: Thank you F. Learning....

Comment: You're very welcome! =) If this answers your question, please consider upvoting the answer and checking the green check-mark below the upvote arrow. Thanks!

Comment: Not enough reputation lol. Did what i could.

Comment: Much appreciated!! =) Also, I've just added a caveat you should pay attention to regarding `LineString`s and `MultiLineString`s.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, the "sort by distance" approach is the idea. The rest is a question of implementation. Good stuff